# AppleScript get the Name of the cell

Tags: numbers, applescript, applescript-numbers

I'm trying to get a script to search a range in a Number's documents for an email address and then tell me what cell that email was in.

```AppleScript
tell application "Numbers" to tell document 1 to tell sheet 1 to tell table 1
    set theEmail to "email@email.com"
    set theRange to range "a:a"
    set theCell to the name of cell is equal to theRange
return theCell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
tell application "Numbers"
    tell document 1 to tell sheet 1 to tell table 1
        set theEmail to "email@email.com"
        set theRange to range "a:a"
        try
            return name of 1st cell of theRange whose value is theEmail
        on error
            return missing value
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot so much frustration gone now.